# Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field \"Query.launches\"

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Schema

```
    type Query {
      launches: [Launch]
    }
    
    type Launch {
      id: String!
      mission_name: String
    }
```

Interface

```
    export interface launch {
      launches: Launch[];
    }
    
    export interface Launch {
      id: string;
      mission_name: string;
    }
```

Service file

```
  async getlaunches(): Promise<any> {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.launchEndpoint));
    this.logger.info('Demonstrate masking of logged data:');
    return await this.apiClient.post(this.launchEndpoint, {
      query: '{ launches { id, mission_name } }',
    });
  }
```

the launchEndpoint is this public URL : https://spacex-production.up.railway.app/

resolver file

```
  @Query('launches')
  async getLaunches(): Promise<any> {
    return this.apiclientService.getlaunches();
  }
```

Controller file

```
      @Get('launches')
      getlaunches(): any {
        return this.apiclientService.getlaunches();
      }
```

I have already tried couple of hours on this issue but no help, let me know if anyone know how to solve it.

Comment: What is your `apiclientService`? Also, why are you returning a `Promise<Observable<launch>>`? You should probably convert the `Observable` to a `Promise` or only use `Observables`. There are use cases for when you need to mix the two, but this doesn't seem like one of them

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Okay i have changes the Observable and now just using the promise. 
apiclientService is just the service class where, i have other functions as well to fetch for other services. 

When i am just call this public api with my query in the code it working well, and giving me the results but when i am using the same through the apollo sandbox its not able to give me desired result.

Comment: Is it using an HTTP client like Axios, node's `http` module, `fetch`, something else? Give specifics here. Does the `apiclientService` handle taking the return body from the HTTP request and parsing it into a form that your application is expecting? Without knowing what you've got, it's gonna be tough to help

Comment: yes its using the the http client axios. I believe the problem might be it can not handle the graphql data, so let me use apollo/client, 

do you have any example using apollo/client for nestjs.

Comment: It seems like the data the server is trying to return is not an array, which would violate the graphql definition